# Bash Search File for Pattern, Replace Pattern With Code that Includes Git Branch Name

Tags: git, bash, github, sed, grep

I have a README.md file where I'd like to replace a text identifier `{{CODESHIP_CODE}}` with a line of code – specifically a build status image code snippet that includes the git branch name.

I'm thinking it would look something like this...

1. Place the current branch `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` in bash variable
2. Place the pattern/string to search for in a variable. This pattern/string is just used as an identifier to quickly locate where in the README.md file I want to output my build status image code.
3. Use `sed` (possibly `grep`) to search the README.md file for the specified `{{CODESHIP_CODE}}` pattern/string and replace it with the build image status code

The code I wrote looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the current branch
function git_branch {
    git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
}

# Set variable to current branch
branch=$(git_branch)

# Define the pattern to search for
# This pattern/string gets replaced with the build status image code
id="{{CODESHIP_CODE}}"

# Create build status image code
# Inject the $branch variable into the correct location
codeship_build_status="[ ![Codeship Status for ExampleGitHubUser/ExampleRepo](https://codeship.com/projects/a99d9999-9b9f-9999-99aa-999a9a9a9999/status?branch=$branch)](https://codeship.com/projects/999999)"

# Find the pattern to replace
# Then replace it with the build status image
sed -i -e "s/{{CODESHIP_CODE}}/$codeship_build_status/g" README.md
```

The problem is that I keep getting the following error:

`sed: 1: "s/{{CODESHIP_CODE}}/[ ! ...": bad flag in substitute command: 'a'`

I'm not sure how to resolve this issue, so that the script works correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a replacement string that contains the unescaped delimiter. Escape the delimiters in the string, or switch to different ones.

```
${codeship_build_status////\\/} # escape
# or
s%{{CODESHIP_CODE}}%$codeship_build_status%g #
```

Make sure the new delimiter isn't contained in the string.

Comment: This was perfect... Per your suggestion I changed the code from ```sed -i -e "s/{{CODESHIP_CODE}}/$codeship_build_status/g" README.md``` to ```sed -i -e "s%{{CODESHIP_CODE}}%$codeship_build_status%g" README.md``` and that worked as expected. Thank you for your help, it's much appreciated!